# How to get notifications of AWS VPC outages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Our CTO received the following notification email from AWS:

> *You're receiving this message because you have at least one VPN Connection in the us-west-1 region. On May 27, 2014 at 16:00 UTC, we
>   will be performing 4 hours of emergent maintenance on the VPN endpoint
>   that has IP address 204.246.163.95. This will affect the following VPN
>   Connections of yours:*
>
> *[id's expurgated]*
>
> *If you have configured your VPN router to use both tunnels, then your
>   VPN Connection to VPC will switch over to the other tunnel for the
>   duration of the maintenance. If you have not configured your VPN
>   router to use both tunnels, then your VPN Connection to VPC will be
>   interrupted for the duration of the maintenance. We encourage you to
>   configure... etc. etc. etc.*

Our CTO got this message because he was the one that originally set up the AWS account. He is not, however, the appropriate person to receive this message. I've done some rooting around AWS, and I have not yet figured out how to get these **specific** kinds of messages routed to the appropriate person. It's a little annoying that every single different AWS service has different ways of doing things... [sigh]. Anyway, can someone tell me how to specify which IAM user or group gets outage notifications or, if indeed, this is possible?

Note that I'm looking for a CLI-style solution that can be called from the AWS SDK. Get me in the ballpark, and I can make the appropriate calls through the .Net API.

Comment: This is not programming related.

Comment: I suppose I should have specified that the answer will get folded into our .NET AWS API based utility application that we use to help us administer stuff in lieu of what is usually painful sets of web GUI screens. I can see your point, but as I'm looking for CLI-style solutions, it kind of straddles the boundary, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS announced the Personal Health Dashboard in Dec. 2016.

As part of this service, you can now use Cloudwatch Events to subscribe to these notices.

So to get an email whenever something in your account needs attention:

- Create an SNS topic
- Add the email as a subscription to the topic
- From the cloudwatch console, select Events, then add a rule
- Pick event pattern, service name should be Health, and pick appropriate event type
- Add your SNS topic to the list of targets

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the root credentials on the AWS Account have the correct contact details. This is the login that has full access on the Account (as opposed to an Identity and Access Management (IAM) login).

It is a good idea to keep the account contact details current, in case there are any issues with your Account (eg regaining access after forgetting a password, or receiving such notifications).